# DNS issues resolving specific site

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

We seem to be having some DNS issues.  At certain times, we loose they ability to get to two particular websites. The problem only seems to be with these two websites that are both hosted by the same company.  At the time we are 
experiencing the issue, NSLOOKUP can not find the sites.  We can access the site via the IP.  Also, if I change the DNS on the local machine to Google's, it works.  That is why I think it may be a problem with our DNS servers.  When I clear the cache on the DNS servers, everything comes back.  NSLOOKUP can find the sites and our users can access them.  After awhile, they go out again.  Can anyone please give me some ideas as to how to find the error.  I really have no idea where to go from here.

Edit:
We are running Windows Server2008 R2.  There are no error messages or reports from the server.  Users just can't get to these two sites.  I was looking for some ideas of what I could research to try and find out why this is happening.  The name of the site is my.providersportal.com.

Edit 2:
I think I may have confused you.  This is not my domain.  Our users are just trying to access it.  Do you have any idea why clearing the cache would fix the issue if it is an issue with the domains NS?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what exactly your problem is. What responses do you get from your DNS cache when you are experiencing problems? What answers were you expecting? What DNS software are you using?

Comment: Yeah, there are plenty of *possibilities*, but you need to narrow this down by providing specifics. We can help, but it will take too much time if we have to throw every possibility at you until one sticks. It will also help if you can provide us the name of the domain. There are some very specific configuration problems we can check for if we have that. It's common to want to withhold that out of privacy, but it's the #1 thing that allows us to answer these questions usefully.

Comment: Even if the domain you have mentioned is not yours, it is misconfigured and this does need fixed. If you can't do it, who ever owns it will have to do it. The issue I have raised in my answer is highly likely to be causing the symptoms you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

CentralNic's Domain Doctor has picked a fair few potential issues with your domain. I would specifically take note of the NS errors where you appear to have completely different NS records on your name servers compared to the NS records being served for your domain by the COM TLD name servers. These are configurable at the domain's registrar. That does need fixed, and is probably what is causing your grief.

Specifically, this inconsistency:

```
$ dig +short -t ns providersportal.com. @a.ns.providersportal.com.
a.ns.providersportal.com.
b.ns.providersportal.com.

$ dig -t ns providersportal.com. @a.gtld-servers.net.
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
providersportal.com.    172800  IN      NS      ns2.000cheapdomains.com.
providersportal.com.    172800  IN      NS      forward.000cheapdomains.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.000cheapdomains.com. 172800 IN      A       209.61.240.234
forward.000cheapdomains.com. 172800 IN  A       67.227.5.75
```

http://manage.centralnic.com/support/domain_doctor/providersportal.com